# OpenJDK in Ubuntu or Android Eclipse

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am new to OpenJDK. Should I install OpenJDK in Ubuntu or is OpenJDK already available in Android Eclipse that I am presently working in? 
If no, then how do I go about installing the OpenJDK in Ubuntu. Please help me.

Comment: Check output of `dpkg -l 'openjdk*'` to see if you've already got it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install openjdk by running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`, (jdk 7). However if you have a working eclipse installation for Java programs chances are that you already have java installed on your machine.

Now to verify it there are following three ways:-

1. Run javac/ java from command line.
2. Manually check the /usr/lib/jvm folder.
3. In Eclipse Go to Window -> preferences -> Java -> installed JREs and see The path of listed JREs there if any .....

Hope it helps!!!

**EDIT 1**
Eclipse is an IDE which helps you in developing applications in various programming languages and Java is just one of them, when you install eclipse it checks whether you have any installed JREs in your system. If the installer can't find any JRE than it gives you a message for that. If it finds any JRE than it takes the path to that JRE and configures itself accordingly.

On the other hand [OpenJDk](http://openjdk.java.net/) is The place to collaborate on an open-source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition, and related projects. You also have sunjdk (oracle's implementation) and many more. For more information about openJdk refer the link.

One more thing  you can install multiple JREs in your machine and choose which one you want to use for any project.

Comment: Thanks. I checked. My Eclipse has JREs. But I want to know if OpenJDK should be installed or I can work in Eclipse environment itself.

Comment: Does OpenJDK work only in Ubuntu or does it come default in Eclipse? I am so confused since I am not finding proper info in net. Please help

Comment: please see the edit...for more information about openJDk see related questions here or google it. Most of us do the same.... cheers!!!

Comment: thanks rahul.. I am installing Vmware player then downloading OpenJDK then installing Java Eclipse again. I guess it will work

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to see java alternatives currently installed on your machine.

Hope this helps. Good luck!